# What is a good convention (or requirement) for the location of the const and virtual keywords in C++?

Tags: c++, virtual

I know the virtual keyword does not need to be resused in a derived class member function declaration if it overrides a virtual base function but is it good practice to do so to make it clear that it is virtual? Also, what about the presence of the const keyword in declaration and/or definition? I think Alexandrescu mentions something about this but I can't recall what it was?

Comment: I'd go with the C++11 `override` at the end instead of `virtual`. That way if your base changes, you'll get a compiler error on top of being clear. `const` always applies to whatever's left unless there is nothing to the left.

Comment: You're asking us to plumb your fuzzy memory? Good luck, it sounds clearer than mine!

Comment: Check this out for [`const`](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question seems very confused. `virtual` is optional when overriding a base-class method. `const` is *never optional* if you need it. This does not do what you think it does:

```
struct A
{
  virtual void Func() const;
};

struct B : public A
{
  virtual void Func();
};
```

The struct `B` has *two* functions named `Func`. One of them will be called when the object it is called on is `const`, and the other will be called when it is not `const`. Nothing in this code has been *overridden*; these are two *separate* virtual functions.

You cannot just ignore the `const` and expect everything to work out fine.

Indeed, this example also shows why you should use `virtual` when you're overriding in derived classes. In this case, it's fairly obvious that you intended to override a base class function, but you got the function signature wrong. Without the `virtual` there, there would not be an immediate indication that you intended to override something.

It's not a huge help, but it's something.

C++11 provides a better solution (in that it actually solves the problem) with the `override` pseudo-keyword.

```
struct A
{
  virtual void Func() const;
};

struct B : public A
{
  virtual void Func() override; //Gives a compiler error, since it is not overriding a base class function.
};
```

Comment: Thanks, I was actually aware of this and what I meant with const was whether to mention it in a prototype (.H) AS WELL as in the .C implementation file..

Comment: @PalaceChan: That also is non-negotiable. Without the `const`, it names a different function, and therefore you'd get a compiler and/or linker error. The `const` is as much a part of the function's type as any of its parameters.